# Forward "Pre-declaring" a Class in C++

Tags: c++, class, substring

I have a situaion in which I want to declare a class member function returning a type that depends on the class itself. Let me give you an example:

```
class Substring {
    private:
        string the_substring_;
    public:
        // (...)
        static SubstringTree getAllSubstring(string main_string, int min_size);
};
```

And SubstringTree is defined as follows:

```
typedef set<Substring, Substring::Comparator> SubstringTree;
```

My problem is that if I put the SubstringTree definition after the Substring definition, the static method says it doesn't know SubstringTree. If I reverse the declarations, then the typedef says it doesn't know Substring.

How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "pre-declaring" is actually called "forward declaration", you'll be much more lucky and get better results using correct term.

Comment: Sorry, I actually forgot what the term was. And come to think about it, had I known what the term was, odds are I would know how do do what I was asking. =)

Comment: Which is why we should include "forward declaration" in answers or comments, so you'll know and any other C++ novice coming on this question should know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define it inside the class:

```
class Substring {
    private:
        string the_substring_;
    public:
        // (...)
        typedef set<Substring, Substring::Comparator> SubstringTree;
        static SubstringTree getAllSubstring(string main_string, int min_size);
};
```

Comment: But then you have to refer to it with  `Substring::SubstringTree`

Comment: ... which may not be a bad idea at all. It would help declutter the global namespace. I'd even go with Substring::Tree.

Comment: But then you can add another typedef outside the class that redefines it in the global scope

Comment: @Ates Goral: Yes, I think `Substring::Tree` would actually be the best solution, but `Substring::SubstringTree` is sort of redundant.

Comment: I'll go with Substring::Tree. Thanks!

Comment: Cluttering the global namespace should be avoided, if possible. I agree that the type should be renamed to `Substring::Tree` though.

Comment: @Zifre Unless you `typedef Substring::SubstringTree SubstringTree;` after the definition of `Substring`. (Though as of C++11 you should prefer `using` to `typedef`.)

Answer (score 8):

As you've written it, the short answer is you can't.

You do have a few close alternatives:

1) Declare SubstringTree in Substring

```
class Substring {
public:
    class Comparator;
    typedef set< Substring, Comparator> Tree;

private:
    string the_substring_;
public:
    // (...)
    static Tree getAllSubstring(string main_string, int min_size);
};

typedef Substring::Tree SubstringTree;
```

2) Define the Comparator outside of Substring:

```
class Substring;
class SubstringComparator;
typedef set< Substring, SubstringComparator> SubstringTree;

class Substring {
public:

private:
    string the_substring_;
public:
    // (...)
    static SubstringTree getAllSubstring(string main_string, int min_size);
};
```

3) You can use a template to delay the lookup until you have more declarations:

```
template <typename String>
struct TreeHelper
{
  typedef set< String, typename String::Comparator> Tree;
};

class Substring {
public:
  class Comparator;

private:
  string the_substring_;
public:
  // (...)
  static TreeHelper<Substring>::Tree getAllSubstring(string main_string
                                             , int min_size);
};

typedef TreeHelper<Substring>::Tree SubstringTree;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can predeclare a class with this:

```
class Foo;
```

Keep in mind that before the class is actually defined, you can only declare pointers to it, not instances.

Answer (score 0):

forward declaration

```
class Substring;
```

I don't know if that will work for non pointer uses of Substring though.